# Run PowerShell Script within Windows 10 service to convert docx to pdf

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have a powershell script to convert docx to pdf. when running in a user session on windows 10 it runs without problems. However, I need to run it within a windows service.

```
$docx_filename = 'C:\temp\doc2pdf.docx'
$pdf_filename = 'C:\temp\doc2pdf1.pdf'

$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$document = $word_app.Documents.Open($docx_filename)
$document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)
$document.Close()

$word_app.Quit()
```

The script is called with the following command

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -File -File "docx2pdf.ps1" -docxFilename "docx2pdf.docx" -pdfFilename "docx2pdf.pdf"
```

With PSSet-Debug -Trace 2 the following is logged

```
DEBUG:   14+   >>>> $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
DEBUG:     ! SET $word_app = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass'.
DEBUG:   16+   >>>> $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($docxFilename)
```

How to get this to work within Windows 10 service?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a batch file which can trigger a powershell script like this:

```
@echo off 
Powershell.exe set-executionpolicy remotesigned -File ScriptPath
```

Save it as "startps.bat"

Then you can use the sc command to create a windows service by mentioning this batch file path like this:

```
Sc create PSScriptService Displayname= "What you like" binpath= "Startps.bat" start= auto
```

Comment: the issue is not to create the service. this works. The powershell scripts hangs when trying to execute the New-Object -ComObject Word.Application statement.

Answer (score 0):

You must set an account on the [service's Log On tab](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-log-on-tab.jpg). Be sure to specify an account where you can log in interactively and run the Powershell script successfully (i.e. where you have installed Word).

But even with that change, you may still run into trouble because Office is [not entirely suitable for operation in a Windows Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Some things work, but some things don't. Try it and let us know how you get on.

Comment: service is already running in the same user context as when I run the script interactively.